# How do I exclude items created on same day in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I'm trying an `exclude()` query to exclude objects created on the same day as a user's profile. The user's `user.created` field is a `DateTimeField`, but I want to exclude all objects created on the same *date* as the user:

I'm trying:

```
my_objects = MyClass.objects.exclude(created__contains=user.created.date())
```

but it throws this error: `Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '%2013-09-14%' for column 'created' at row 1`

Is there a better way or a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare [year](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year), [month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month), [day](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#day):

```
d = user.created
my_objects = MyClass.objects.exclude(
    created__year=d.year,
    created__month=d.month,
    created__day=d.day
)
```

or compare with the date (inclusive) and the next day (exclusive)

```
d = user.created.date()
my_objects = MyClass.objects.exclude(
    created__gte=d,
    created__lt=d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
)
```